# Use assets folder images for gallery

Tags: android, image, assets, android-assets

I am creating an android application.In that one layout file uses a gallery.

I want to know how to use the images from assets folder as gallery images.

for e.g.

> for a specific layout file **new_am.xml** I use the images from **assets/new_am** folder for the **Gallery** of that layout.

I know how to use it in case of minimum amount of images , but in my app each folder in assets contains more than 50 images.

Comment: `one layout file uses a gallery.` ?? What do you mean by that? Files do not use galleries. Did you mean instead "how to display images from assets in a GridView?

Comment: In my app I have a layout.xml file with a Gallery and I want to use the images from assets folder as the images of the gallery.

Comment: Please show the xml file. Also show your code doing it with a minimum amout of images. 50 is not very much so i wonder why that would give a problem. Please also explain why you can retrieve two files from assets and not 59.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically access assets folders and set images to Gallery like below,

```
File fA=new File("file:///android_asset/folderA");  
File[] filesA =fA.listFiles();

File fB=new File("file:///android_asset/folderB");  
File[] filesB =fB.listFiles();
```

Also you can collect asset's folders names dynamically.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No this will not work. "file:///android_asset/..." is only for a WebView.

Comment: Can you help me to do this??

Answer (score -1):

```
        // to reach asset
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        // to get all item in dogs folder.
        String[] images = assetManager.list("FolderA");

        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("FolderA/" + images[0]);

        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(d); //set to an Image view
        inputStream.close();
```